# Windows Azure SQL login - password expire

Tags: sql, azure, authentication, passwords, azure-sql-database

Two questions on Windows Azure SQL logins:

1. How do I find out when a DB user changed his password? In SQL Server I used the LOGINPROPERTY for this, but in Azure this doesn't seem to work.
2. How do I enfore Azure SQL User's login expiration in Azure? Seems that this isn't supported when creating a login. What if I want the user to change his DB password at least every 90 days?

Please note that I am talking about DB logins and not Windows.

Comment: Azure does not support CHECK_EXPIRATION. It is OFF by default.